# How to display graph in excel with the percentage data

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I am creating one graph in excel to show all my concluded data in the consolidated graph format. I tried multiple logic but unable to do generate graph.

Could you please suggest me solution for graph with below data:

[image]

I created the graph, but for that I have to add specific value instead of margin value.

Comment: So how would you expect it to look like?

Comment: your table does not contain any numeric numbers. "10-15%" is a text string. what kind of graph you are interested in? based on the dataset of your table can you sketch the graph you wish for?

Comment: I want to generate Bar graph with these data.